# How to fill a lateral div with text 100% height? (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I'd like to fill a lateral div with a color and that it takes the 100% of the page's height. I'm also using a dropdown menu, and I think this is the problem, but I'm not sure.

I'd like to show you how it should look:

---

|   DIV with image |  -------------------------------------------      Div with Some text       ------------------------------------- |

---

| Image | DropDown Menu 1 | DD Menu 2 | DD Menu 3|----------------          |  Div I want to have 100% height |

---

| -------------------------------------- Content -------------------------------------| ------- Div continues ↑ ----------- |

| -------------------------------------- Content -------------------------------------| ------- Div continues ↑ ----------- |

| -------------------------------------- Content -------------------------------------| ------- Div continues ↑ ----------- |

---

And so on, depending on the content.

Here's a screenshot of the problem.
http://postimg.org/image/9r9mgg3yf/

That green div is the one I wanna show with 100% of the height (red circle), and if it's posible, to keep showing the text or maybe put an image on it, but I really want it to take the 100%. As you can see, it also puts the vertical scrollbar when it shouldn't.

I appreciate your help. Here is the code:

```js
$(this.document).ready(function () {
            $('ul#ul1 li ul').hide();

            $('ul#ul1 li').hover(
                function () {
                    $('ul#ul1 li').not($('ul', this)).stop();
                    $('ul', this).slideDown('fast');
                },

                function () {
                    $('ul', this).slideUp('fast');
                }
            );
        });
```

```css
   html, body {
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
   }

   #one
   {
    background:white;
    width:30%;
    height:10%;
    float:left;    
   }
   
   #two
   {
       background:green;
       width:70%;
       height:10%;
       color:white;
       font-size:19pt;
       text-align:center;
       float:right;
   }

   #three
   {
       background:#FF6600; 
       width:10%;
       height:200%;
       float:right;
       color:white;
       font-size:16pt;
   }
   
   #four
   {
          background:gray;
          width:90%;
          height:10%;
          float:left;
                font-size:18px;
          color:white;
             display: block;
             -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
             -moz-border-radius: 5px;
             border-radius: 5px;
   }
   
   #form1 {
                text-align: center;
            }

            ul#ul1, ul#ul1 ul {
             list-style: none;
             padding: 5px;
            }

            ul#ul1 li {
             display: block;
             float: left;
             margin:0;
             padding: 5px 20px 15px 20px;
             position: relative;
             line-height: 18px;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 119px;
                height: 13px;
            }

            ul#ul1 li a {
             color: #FAFAFA;
             text-decoration: none;
            }

            ul#ul1 a:hover{
             color:#fff;
            }

            ul#ul1 li ul {
             background: #E1E1E1;
             border-bottom: solid 2px #C1C1C1;
             border-top: solid 2px #D1D1D1;
             border-left: solid 1px #D1D1D1;
             border-right: solid 1px #D1D1D1;
             margin: 12px 0 0 0;
             padding: 0 10px 0;
             width: 130px;
             position: absolute;
            }

            ul#ul1 li ul li {
             border-bottom: 1px solid #C1C1C1;
             display: block;
             float: none;
             height: 14px;
             padding: 18px 0;
             text-align: center;
             margin: 0;
             width: 130px;
             background: none;
            }

            ul#ul1 li ul li.last {
             border-bottom: none;
            }

            ul#ul1 li ul li a {
             color: #313131;
            }

            ul#ul1 li ul li a:hover {
             color: #000;
            }

            ul#ul1 li ul li:last-child:not(li.arrow){
             border: 0;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formMinutasAdm" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="True"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

        <div id="one">
            <center>
                <img alt="Image" src="Resources/Image.png" width="60%" style="height: 90px" />
            </center>
        </div>

        <div id="two">
            <br />
            Some text
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>

        <div id="three">
            <br />
            <track> &nbsp; T<br />
                &nbsp; e<br />
                &nbsp;  x<br />
                &nbsp; t<br />
                &nbsp; 
                <br />
                &nbsp; 0
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <center> &nbsp; 1<br />&nbsp; T<br />&nbsp; e<br />&nbsp; x<br /> </center>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <center>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; T<br />&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; e<br />&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; x<br />
   &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; t<br />&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; 0<br />&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; 1 </center>
            </track>
            <br />
        </div>

        <div id="four">
            <ul id="ul1">
                <li><a href="#">
                    <img alt="DDSW" src="Resources/ddsw.png" style="width: 22%; height: 19px; position: relative; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" /></a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#">Menu1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a id="btnAccess" href="#1">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAccess" runat="server" BackColor="#E1E1E1" BorderColor="#E1E1E1" Width="120px" BorderStyle="None" Height="25px" Font-Size="15.5px" Text="Create" Style="text-align: left" OnClick="btnAccess_Click" TabIndex="30" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                        </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#2">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAccessModify" runat="server" BackColor="#E1E1E1" BorderColor="#E1E1E1" Width="120px" BorderStyle="None" Height="25px" Font-Size="15.5px" Text="Modify" Style="text-align: left" OnClick="btnAccessModify_Click" TabIndex="31" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                        </a></li>

                        <li <%= this.btnDelete %>><a href="#2">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAccessDelete" runat="server" BackColor="#E1E1E1" BorderColor="#E1E1E1" Width="120px" BorderStyle="None" Height="25px" Font-Size="15.5px" Text="Delete" Style="text-align: left" OnClick="btnAccessDelete_Click" TabIndex="32" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                        </a></li>

                        <li class="last"><a href="#3">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAccessQuery" runat="server" BackColor="#E1E1E1" BorderColor="#E1E1E1" Width="120px" BorderStyle="None" Height="25px" Font-Size="15.5px" Text="Query" Style="text-align: left" TabIndex="33" OnClick="btnAccessQuery_Click" />
                            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="PopUpQuery" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="PanelPopUpQuery" TargetControlID="Button4">
                            </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
                        </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Menu2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#4">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAccessGetReport" runat="server" BackColor="#E1E1E1" BorderColor="#E1E1E1" Width="120px" BorderStyle="None" Height="25px" Font-Size="15.5px" Text="Get Report" Style="text-align: left" TabIndex="34" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClick="btnAccessGetReport_Click" />
                        </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#5">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAccessGenerateReport" runat="server" BackColor="#E1E1E1" BorderColor="#E1E1E1" Width="120px" BorderStyle="None" Height="25px" Font-Size="15.5px" Text="Generate Report" Style="text-align: left" TabIndex="35" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClick="btnAccessGenerateReport_Click" />
                        </a></li>
                        <li class="last"><a href="#6">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAccessHistory" runat="server" BackColor="#E1E1E1" BorderColor="#E1E1E1" Width="120px" BorderStyle="None" Height="25px" Font-Size="15.5px" Text="History" Style="text-align: left" TabIndex="36" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClick="btnAccessHistory_Click" />
                        </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Menu3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#7">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAccessInformation" runat="server" BackColor="#E1E1E1" BorderColor="#E1E1E1" Width="120px" BorderStyle="None" Height="25px" Font-Size="15.5px" Text="Información" Style="text-align: left" TabIndex="37" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClick="btnAccessInformation_Click" />
                        </a></li>
                        <li class="last"><a href="#8">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnAccessSession" runat="server" BackColor="#E1E1E1" BorderColor="#E1E1E1" Width="120px" BorderStyle="None" Height="25px" Font-Size="15.5px" Text="Cerrar Sesión" Style="text-align: left" OnClick="btnAccessSession_Click" TabIndex="38" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
                        </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I understood what you were asking, but if I missed it let me know.

You have height set to 100% but 100% of what? It's always the parent of that element so what is the parent's height set to? If it's not set to anything then the browser has nothing to reference.

So I positioned it absolutely - it will now take the browsers height and calculate based on that.

& if you don't want it to show white space underneath, which is the extra content you put in there, you need to put overflow:hidden on the containing element.

Js Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zspj4q99/3/

here is the code I changed:

```
#three{
            background:#FF6600; 
            width:10%;
            height:100%;
            color:white;
            font-size:16pt;
            position:absolute;
            right:8px;
            top:95px;
            overflow:hidden;

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked great! The main problem I had was to check the parent for each div, and according to that, assign the percent of size. Thanks for your help!